# Is it possible to insert a system command into a runOnce registry key/value?

Tags: batch, script, windows-registry

For context, I have a script that runs a procedure, then reboots the computer, after reboot one directory needs to be recursively removed.

Is this possible to do by using a "built-in" Windows 10 command, by calling directly or inline, as a registry value in runOnce registry key pair?

Comment: Yes, very much so.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744482/run-on-windows-startup-cmd-with-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script can insert a RUNONCE key in the registry for an action to be done only once
on reboot or login of a specific user. Administrator permissions are required
for updating the registry.

The registry keys are:

- On reboot : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
- Current user : `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

For the RunOnce key to be deleted only if its task is run successfully,
prepend the key name value with an exclamation mark `!`.

If you want the RunOnce command to run even in Safe Mode, prepend the
key name value with an asterisk `*`.

The RunOnce script should not insert new RunOnce entries in the registry.

Examples:

**For reboot**

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v RunScript /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\\setup\\script.cmd\""
```

**For current user** (HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v RunScript /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\\setup\\script.cmd\"" /f
```

**For a specific user (HKEY_USERS)**

```
reg add HKU\S-1-5-21-3492930481-2827506072-2794401122-1001\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v RunScript /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\\setup\\script.cmd\"" /f
```

**All user profiles**

```
FOR /D %%D IN ("C:\Users\*") DO IF EXIST "%%D\NTUSER.DAT" REG LOAD HKU\TEMP "%%D\NTUSER.DAT" && (reg add HKU\TEMP\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v Reg_Value /t REG_SZ /d Reg_Data /f & REG UNLOAD HKU\TEMP)
```